# Breadcrumb levels (over 2) not displayed correctly using MvcSiteMapProvider

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-2, sitemap, breadcrumbs, mvcsitemapprovider

I am using MvcSiteMapProvider and it shows just 2 levels of bread instead of 3 or 4 sometime.

Instead of:

```
Categories > List > item1
```

Shows just:

```
List > item1
```

This is my Mvc.sitemap:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<mvcSiteMap xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
            xmlns="http://mvcsitemap.codeplex.com/schemas/MvcSiteMap-File-2.0"
            xsi:schemaLocation="http://mvcsitemap.codeplex.com/schemas/MvcSiteMap-File-2.0 MvcSiteMapSchema.xsd"
            enableLocalization="true">
<mvcSiteMapNode title="$resources:mvc.sitemap,menu_Home" controller="Home" action="Index" visibility="InSiteMapPathOnly" changeFrequency="Always">
<mvcSiteMapNode title="$resources:mvc.sitemap,menu_Categories" controller="Category" action="Categories">
            <mvcSiteMapNode title="$resources:mvc.sitemap,menu_List" controller="Category" action="Index">
                <mvcSiteMapNode title="$resources:mvc.sitemap,menu_item1" controller="Category" action="Action1" />
                <mvcSiteMapNode title="$resources:mvc.sitemap,menu_item2" controller="Category" action="Action2"/>
            </mvcSiteMapNode>
</mvcSiteMapNode>
</mvcSiteMap>
```

Comment: How are you calling the bread crumb in your code?

Comment: Html.MvcSiteMap().SiteMapPath()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a typo in above post (missing / in first mvcSiteMapNode), but the issue still occurrs after fixing it.

However, this problem is fixed in new version of MvcSiteMapProvider MVC4 (and MvcSiteMapProvider MVC5).

Working code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<mvcSiteMap xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
            xmlns="http://mvcsitemap.codeplex.com/schemas/MvcSiteMap-File-2.0"
            xsi:schemaLocation="http://mvcsitemap.codeplex.com/schemas/MvcSiteMap-File-2.0 MvcSiteMapSchema.xsd"
            enableLocalization="true">
<mvcSiteMapNode title="$resources:mvc.sitemap,menu_Home" controller="Home" action="Index" visibility="InSiteMapPathOnly" changeFrequency="Always" />
<mvcSiteMapNode title="$resources:mvc.sitemap,menu_Categories" controller="Category" action="Categories">
            <mvcSiteMapNode title="$resources:mvc.sitemap,menu_List" controller="Category" action="Index">
                <mvcSiteMapNode title="$resources:mvc.sitemap,menu_item1" controller="Category" action="Action1" />
                <mvcSiteMapNode title="$resources:mvc.sitemap,menu_item2" controller="Category" action="Action2"/>
            </mvcSiteMapNode>
</mvcSiteMapNode>
</mvcSiteMap>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem may be occurring because the Mvc.sitemap file's contents are invalid. The `mvcSiteMapNode` tag for the Home/Index controller/action is missing its closing tag.